# Array size known only at runtime in MIPS

Tags: arrays, dynamic, assembly, mips

So I have a board game and the user is expected to enter the size of the board
3,4,5 ...will be 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, etc...

Here:

```
board: .word 0:100  # declare a board of size 100 and make ints '0' , O = 1, X = 2
```

As you can see, this is static declaration...I need to somehow make an array the SIZE of the user input found in t0 for example...

Comment: There's a trick if you add a label right before and another one right after... then you can do pointer arithmetic to get the length

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you need to allocate some memory on the heap. The MARS emulator `syscall` for that is $v0 = 9, $a0 = number of bytes to allocate, returns address of allocated memory in $v0. Source: [MIPS syscall functions available in MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)

So your steps would be:

- Get the array size from the user
- Square it
- Make syscall 9 with the size you calculated