# How to allocate an array of variable size in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to learn MIPS. Problem I encountered is that I can't create array of variable size. For instance in Java you can do

```
int n = 3;
int [] arr = new int[n];
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in MIPS with something like:

```
.text 
.global main

main:
li $t1, 4

.data
arr: .space $t1
```

But this gives an error:

> ".space" requires a non-negative integer

Any suggestions? How can I solve this.

Comment: By "variable size", are you looking to create it at runtime?  Because I suppose you can just use `arr: .space 4` instead.

Comment: yup, but then I want to make it so that user inputs some integer and then I want array of that integer size.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436316/array-size-known-only-at-runtime-in-mips

Comment: Ok, answer it and I'll accept

Comment: If you're allocating on the stack (what would be locally scoped in C), you just save the current stack pointer as the start position of the array, then advance the stack pointer by the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19436316/7294647), one solution would be to allocate space on the heap for your array.  Assuming you're using MARS to run your MIPS code, you can load `9` into `$v0` and `$a0` should represent the number of bytes of memory to allocate.  You should then perform a `syscall`.

The address of the allocated memory is then returned in `$v0`.